# copying a texture in xna into another texture

Tags: xna

I am loading a Texture2D that contains multiple sprite textures. I would like to pull the individual textures out when I load the initial Texture to store into separate Texture2D objects, but can't seem to find a method any where that would let me do this. SpriteBatch.Draw I believe should only be called from within a begin, end block right?

Thanks.

Comment: you are right about the last part. Draw must be called between begin and end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am loading a Texture2D that contains
>   multiple sprite textures. I would like
>   to pull the individual textures out
>   when I load the initial Texture to
>   store into separate Texture2D objects.

You don't have to do this nor should you. Accessing a single texture is faster than multiple textures. Also, textures are stored in GPU texture memory. It just makes no sense to split it up.

You should instead focus on writing code that can access individual sprites within your sprite sheet. I suggest you have a look at how sprite based games work.

Here is a great tutorial video series that should help you out: [tile engine videos](http://nickgravelyn.com/archive/#tileengine)

Comment: I came across this same information. I have refactored my code to use a source rectangle instead of each Sprite storing a Texture2D.

Comment: Sprite sheets act weird in XNA on some graphics cards -- even if you're using the correct source rectangle, if you are blitting to a stretched rectangle, the surrounding pixels in your sprite could influence what gets rendered -- if you copy each tile from your sheet into it's own texture, that issue goes away completely.